# Preventing Re-submission of data on Browser Refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have a form.  On submit of a button, it inserts a record into the db.   If I go back in my browser and refresh the page it's resubmitting it causing all sorts of issues as you can imagine.  How do I ensure that the user can't refresh the previous page and the state of that page does another automatic submit on refresh like this?

1. I'm not using ViewState.  I actually have it disabled in the page directive
2. No, Response.Redirect does NOT solve this problem.  The user can still go back with the browser's back button and refresh at the point where they submitted and it will still run the button's event sending the data downstream to my DL insert

Comment: Should the second submission actually be *illegal*, or is it just *usually* unintended?

Comment: Many People are searching answers for this question.  Me too included in that list.  Problem is every one states "Program your code so that this can be avoided"... like distint field in DB... But there are lots of ifs and Buts in it.  As of now, I'm still searching...

Answer (score 3):

The solution I use most often is this:

When the user first visits the page (Non-PostBack), generate a token value (GUID is easy). Take this token value and store it in their Session variables and a hidden field in the page. Being a field, this value should persist through round trips to the server without ViewState enabled (I could be mistaken on that count, so please check it!). Should the page be refreshed (and form values lost), a new value will be generated by the Non-PostBack initialization.

When the page is posted back, retrieve the hidden field value and compare it against the expected value in the user's Session variables:

- If the tokens match, accept the submission as "genuine", remove the token from the Session variables, and continue your workflow.
- If the token is missing from Session variables, the user is trying to submit the form again. - If the tokens do not match, the user is "replaying" an old submission of the form.

Example code to achieve this sort of solution:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    protected HiddenField tokenField; 

    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
            CreateToken();
    }

    // Call this method to establish a token in session and on the page.
    private void CreateToken()
    {
        string token = new Guid().ToString();
        Session["dupeToken"] = token;
        tokenField.Value = token;
    }

    // Call this method to validate the token before continuing workflow.
    private bool TokenIsValid()
    {
        string expectedToken = (string)Session["dupeToken"];
        if(expectedToken == null)
            return false;

        string actualToken = tokenField.Value;

        return expectedToken == actualToken;
    }

    // Call this method when the page submission is complete to prevent re-submission.
    private void ConsumeToken()
    {
        Session["dupeToken"] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you hit the back button and 'replay' the submission, the tokens will match: just like any other form element, the hidden field that stores the original token is unchanged.

Comment: They should not, since the token is only generated on visits to the form where values are not present in the fields (i.e. a unique submission). Since the token is "consumed" in Session on a submission, it will not be present for replays of the form.

Comment: The problem is that blasted 'Back' button: when you use the back button to navigate to a page from which you posted, all its form input elements (including hidden fields) have the values you used for the original post. Hence, the original token is still there when the user resubmits.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what token is available on the page, because there will not be a token in Session variables. The key to this approach is having the same token in both the form and Session.

Comment: I didn't see that you added a method (ConsumeToken) - until just now. +1 - this works, and it's simpler than the solution I suggested. (It might be worth noting that you consume the token on submission / save in your text though.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to wrap the form in an `< asp:UpdatePanel>`.  That way, all postbacks are done via AJAX and the browser will never ask you to re-submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

The best two ways of doing this are:

1. Performing a check on a distinct field against the database
2. Create a hidden token in the form that uses a salt based on time. If you put logic in script to check for the existing time and compare it to the token, you can either allow the submission or define it. For example, if the form is drawn at a certain time, you store the token, and within 30-60 seconds you can submit, but after that you cannot.